# Sites or youtube videos to learn algebraic geometry

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Is there any sites or free lecture videos to learn algebraic geometry? or should I call abstract algebra?

I want to understand about rings, ideals, and real spectrum of rings but my understanding on it is near 0.

If anyone have some recommendation video or anything  (as long as it is free :) ) for commoners (for people whose major is not math) to learn things that I mentioned above, please let me know. Many thanks in advance.

Cheers!

Comment: Just so you know, algebraic geometry is different from abstract algebra.

Comment: Have you tried searching "algebra" in youtube? I remember I have seen quite a few good quality math related videos from channels backed by MIT.

Comment: I thought abstract algebra and algebraic geometry is the same thing ^^

Answer (score 4):

In order to learn algebraic geometry you will be best off with a good grounding in abstract algebra (groups, rings etc.) and then some commutative algebra (though I guess it's possible to learn some of this as you go along).
Searching MIT opencourseware and similar sites for these topics might work out well, and http://www.extension.harvard.edu/open-learning-initiative/abstract-algebra looks like a good start to me.

As for videos on algebraic geometry, these may be harder to find, but there are some at https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLY28_CByrwHZ0UOqfuw6KVgKIE6-Go0RG at least and there are probably others elsewhere.

Comment: So I should learn Abstract Algebra first before I go to Algebraic Geometry?

Comment: @mathNewbie89 Yes, otherwise it will be really hard to understand anything!

Answer (score 1):

There're numerous online resources for preliminary materials such as MIT open courseware. There's a growing list in this MO topic [Video Lectures in Algebraic Geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78037/video-lectures-for-algebraic-geometry) containing rather more advanced materials. Including more math areas, there's the following list [Video lectures of mathematics courses available online for free](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54430/video-lectures-of-mathematics-courses-available-online-for-free) as well.