# Video lectures of algebraic geometry (Hartshorne, Shafarevich, ... )

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, soft-question, big-list, online-resources

I am a commutative algebra student.

> Are there any *video* lectures on algebraic geometry available online for free?

I'd like the lectures to cover main topics of the books like *Hartshorne*'s "*Algebraic Geometry*" or *Shafarevich*'s book, "*Basic Algebraic Geometry*."

I want to download, but if it is not for download, or isn't a career, please post it; it may be helpful for others.

I've read "*Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms*" by Cox, Little and O'Shea and almost 3 chapters of "*Algebraic Geometry*" of J.S. Milne, but there are gaps.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751966/sites-or-youtube-videos-to-learn-algebraic-geometry/752009#752009

Comment: Alex J Best: thanks. +1

Comment: Are you interested in courses not in English?

Comment: @sas: English, Arabic, Turkish, Farsi, are good for me. but if there is a course not in these, please post it. (to help others)

Comment: Harpreet Bedi has nice videos [here](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCErLELnXehsJ7ycW4OJgfQQ/playlists).

Comment: @PhilippeMalot Who is harpreet bedi exactly? His blog or youtube channel has no information about him

Answer (score 9):

these are not complete answers, but may help someone:
[this is not for download](http://vod.mathnet.or.kr/sub1.php?key_year=&key_subject=&key_conf=&key_semi=&key_sort=&key_s_title=&key_title=algebraic+geometry&key_name=&x=26&y=9). this has 11156's answer and more.
see also [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLCgncMh0TrCkiiuBH1fcioW8uFO9S_KPE) and [here](https://www.msri.org/workshops/470) and [here](https://www.msri.org/web/msri/online-videos)

Answer (score 3):

One can search [here](http://ium.mccme.ru/IUM-video.html). There are lectures **in Russian** from Moscow Center for Continuous Mathematical Education. There are videos, notes and exercise sheets.

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen http://nptel.ac.in/courses/111106097/ ? It is by Balaji at IIT Madras. It covers : Affine Varieties, Hilbert's Basis Theorem and the Hilbert Nullstellensatz, projective and quasi-projective varieties, morphisms, rational maps and function fields, nonsingularity, smooth varieties (from the syllabus).

Answer (score 3):

Another course of Algebraic Geometry in English by [Lothar Göttsche](https://users.ictp.it/~gottsche/) (International Centre for Theoretical Physics) is now available in [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLLq_gUfXAnkkeQKfjfWwyJP8eUV08Kygd) (90 min. × 20). (The first video lecture is posted in December 2016.)

As far as I watched, the materials covered in the lecture is almost based on his [lecture note](https://users.ictp.it/~gottsche/algcourse.ps).